# Using ALL tenses in this text

Tags: grammar, tense, grammaticality, usage, grammaticality-in-context

I wrote an imaginary text in which I used all tenses (12 tenses) to familiarize with them. The tenses are:

> PAST: Past simple, Past perfect simple, Past continuous, Past perfect continuous.
>
> PRESENT: Present simple, Present perfect simple, Present continuous, Present perfect continuous.
>
> FUTURE: Future (will), Future perfect simple, Future continuous, Future perfect continuous.

**Then what I ask here is: advice about my text**, because me as a non-native english speaker I do not know if I am using the tenses correctly or not.

I got help from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/), where I got information about tenses in grammar section.

So, I will start with the text...:

> **My diary:**
>
> *16/12/2019 - The crazy day*:
>
> This is the most weird day that **I have ever had** (`Present perfect simple`). **I had been walking** (`Past perfect continuous`) to my friend's house when (=suddenly) **I saw** (`Past simple`) a bull in the street!. In that moment, I ran too fast to the opposite direcion meanwhile **I was screaming** (`Past continuous`) for help. **I had experienced** (`Past perfect simple`) a similar situation like that, but in a secure environment (with fences).
>
> **I have** (`Present simple`) a mix of feelings now. **I am thinking** (`Present continuous`) about before, **I have been running** (`Present perfect continuous`) too fast, I thought that the bull was near me after that race.
>
> The next year **I will have been writting** (`Future perfect continuous`) in this diary for 10 years, and this is the most weird fact that I have ever had.
>
> Now, what I want is: talk with my friend face-to-face about that moment, so, I think that **I will go** (`Future: will`) to his house tomorrow (**I will be checking** (`Future continuous`) well the path, because I could see other one again!)
>
> I will close this crazy day with the hope that for the next year **I will not have lived** (`Future perfect simple`) another day like this.

**I add to my first question: Could you check the last sentence?** Because I used the **future perfect simple** and I am doubting about its use in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Your last sentence using the future perfect simple tense( future perfect tense) is adequate for the following reasons.
1/It describe an event in the future that hasn't happened and is in no way planned.
2/Said(anticipated) event take place prior in time of the stated time of recollection."for the next year"
However, since you used "for the next year" as your designated time of recollection therefore it is slightly more appropriate to use the future continuous tense.(For more clarity and formality)

Answer (score 0):

In your post, I believe that using the past continuous in place of  the past perfect continuous tense would have made more sense.
You didn't state the duration of the action while emphasizing the interruption of the said action.This is the textbook definition of the past continuous tense.